Pytesseract sees random chars
I use '--psm 6' as config. And i have pytesseract 4.1.1. Language: 'deu' which is German
In various documents pytesseract recognizes chars which are not there.
For example I have this image. We can see that there are strings which are not in the document. And this is not a once time result, all of my documents have this kind of problem.

Another example is this one. There is no "re"

in the document.
Any suggestions? How can I solve it?
Until now I tried some image preparation.
def prepare_image_advanced(image):
    cv2_image = np.array(image)
    cv2_image = cv2.resize(src=cv2_image, dsize=None, fx=1, fy=1)
    cv2_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    _, binary = cv2.threshold(cv2_image, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    kernel = np.ones((25, 25), np.uint8)
    closed = cv2.morphologyEx(binary, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
        closed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    )

    for j, contour in enumerate(contours[:-1]):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2_image[y : y + h, x : x + w] = 255

    prepared_image = Image.fromarray(cv2_image)

    # brightener = ImageEnhance.Brightness(prepared_image)
    # prepared_image = brightener.enhance(1.5)
    # contraster = ImageEnhance.Contrast(prepared_image)
    # prepared_image = contraster.enhance(1.5)
    # sharpener = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(prepared_image)
    # prepared_image = sharpener.enhance(1.5)

    # prepared_image = np.array(prepared_image)

    return prepared_image

Which looks like this. It does not help actually.
